# Get angular module name in javascript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I want to get `Angular Module` name in `JavaScript`.

Means i want to retrieve module name of angular js application in my javascript file so that i can apply other functionality on that module.

I want to get value of `ng-app` or `data-ng-app`

Comment: how does any of the *existing* angular code work at all, if you don't know the name of the module?  It's not really clear what you are truly asking for here, or why it would be practical.

Comment: Just query the element that attribute is attached to and get the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','$rootElement',
    function($scope, $rootElement) {
        console.log($rootElement.attr('ng-app'));  
    }
]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/8q7b5ttw/)**

Comment: No i want to get in other javascript file not in same file where i have define `app = angular.module('.........')`

Comment: @JivaniJaydeep you cannot do that

Comment: I'm creating one plugin and in that i want to get user's application module dynamically so i can apply my plugin functionality on that same module..